# Object is not defined after Webpack bundling

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I have simple app wrote in ES6 for the training purpose. I want to use modules in this app, so I installed webpack and babel. Unfortunetaly, when I try to fire my method, I receive the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: gas is not defined
at HTMLButtonElement.count (bundle.js:113)
```

So, 'gas' is my instance of the object.

Here are my files:
main.js

```
'use strict'

import Gas from "./gas";

const count = document.getElementById("gas-count");

const gas = new Gas();

count.addEventListener("click", gas.count);
```

gas.js

```
export default class Gas {
  constructor() {

  }

  count() {
    // code
  }

  printResult(result) {
    // code
  }

  _isValid(dist, price, aver) {
   // Code
  }
};
```

Finally, here is my Webpack config:

```
module.exports = {

  // Define entry point
  entry: "./src/main.js",

  // Define output point
  output: {
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      loader: "babel-loader",
      query: {
        presets: ["env"]
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

I'd be really grateful if someone could give me a hint why it's not working. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it looks like it should work. what output do you have here:  import Gas from "./gas"; console.log (Gas)

Comment: This is my console log:
function Gas() {
    _classCallCheck(this, Gas);
  }